# How can i make constant variance for ARIMA model?

Tags: variance, arima, data-transformation, stationarity

I want to fit ARIMA model to univariate time series. For this i took log then difference twice but the variance of the series is not constant. i also try with box.cox transformation but variance is not constant. Please can you suggest how can i make constant variance for my data series.[image: second difference log data]

[image: original time series plot]